# Как в Java создать простую таблицу (без заголовков - только ячейки).

Tags: jtable, eclipse, java

И как в ней задавать количество строк и столбцов.
Еще лучше было бы узнать, как сделать такую таблицу прямо из GUI, а сколько строк и столбцов в ней задавать в программе.
И еще хотелось бы узнать, можно ли такую таблицу сделать в Visual Studio на C#.

Answer (score 2):

вот тут все разжевано http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html
причем тут Visual Studio и C#?

Comment: Ну в c# есть DataGridView, других таблиц я не смог найти (среди элементов). Вот и стало интересно, можно ли в c# сделать простую табличку. За ссылку спасибо)